# Postfix server block outgoing fake domain permit only one domain

Tags: centos, email, postfix

We are having postfix mail server in centos webserver. In that server users able to send from fake email id like admin@gmail.com and all.

But I am having only one domain in that server, So I need to block fake Id and give permission only for my example.com domain.

Is it possible if I edit /etc/postfix/header_checks or in transport we will block.

All the outgoing mail will go with my example.com only. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 2):

To force that users use email address like something@example.lan for mail sended  from  inside the server, you can use this configuration

```
smtpd_restriction_classes =
   inside

inside =
  check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/allowed_senders
  reject

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   reject_unauth_destination
   check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/inside_network
   ... your favourite anti spam stuff here ...
   permit
```

/etc/postfix/inside_network

```
127.0.0.1               inside
hostname.example.lan    inside
```

in /etc/postfix/allowed_senders:

```
example.lan     OK
```

**Source:**
http://www.arschkrebs.de/postfix/postfix_restriction_classes3_en.shtml
http://www.arschkrebs.de/postfix/postfix_restriction_classes2_en.shtml

Answer (score 1):

After i had the same problem, and a quick search, i found the following (ripped off http://www.bentasker.co.uk/documentation/linux/161-configuring-postfix-to-block-outgoing-mail-to-all-but-one-domain)

Thought i share it here

---

Use Transport Mapping
Using this method, we can tell Postfix to either reject the mail, or disregard it. The latter is generally the preferred method as we want the sending application to believe the mail has been sent.

First we need to edit the postfix configuration file

```
nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Now search for transport_maps (Ctrl-W, transport_maps -> Enter). You shouldn't find anything (if you do, skip the next step, but make note of which file is listed)

Add a line reading

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

*Note: Depending on the version of Postfix you're running, you could use texthash which would avoid needing to run postmap on the file. It's up to the reader to work out which route they'd prefer, but if your postfix version is < 2.8 you can't use texthash.*

Save and close (Ctrl-X, Y -> Enter)

Now we need to update the transport maps (if you didn't need to add a line, subsitute the relevant file path here)

```
nano /etc/postfix/transport
```

Now we need to add a line specifying which domain to allow sending to (I'm going to allow to bentasker.co.uk). To do so, insert the following lines

```
example.com :
* discard:
```

This will simply discard messages to any email address not of the domain bentasker.co.uk. If you wanted to reject with an error you'd use (set the error text to suit your needs)

```
example.com:
* error: Only allowing one domain
```

*Note: Simply add additional domains on the line after bentasker.co.uk:, one line per domain.*

Save and close (Ctrl-X, Y -> Enter)

Now we need to create a hash of the file (unless you used texthash in main.cf)

```
postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```

Finally, we need Postfix to reload it's rules

```
/etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

Job done! You should now find that emails sent to domains not specified are silently discarded, whilst those for whitelisted domains go through as normal. Be sure to check that the change has worked though, mailq and the maillog are your friends!

For non-whitelisted domains you should see the message being removed in the maillog but with no connection taking place before hand, and relay showing as none (there may be no sign of a connection, but if relay != none there's a very good chance the mail was sent).

**Source: http://www.bentasker.co.uk/documentation/linux/161-configuring-postfix-to-block-outgoing-mail-to-all-but-one-domain**

Comment: With this config, every user on your server can send emails with any local part. User1 logs in (who has the adress `user1@example.com`) and sends a mail with the From-Adress `user2@example.com`. Postfix thinks it's valid, because the domain matches, but the User1 should be allowed to send in the name of User2.