# Restricting outgoing mail to specific domains in From Address using Postfix

Tags: postfix

For reasons that make me want to hurt myself, an application I am required to support has the ability to send mail using a 'MAIL FROM' address of any domain. Because I am unable to lock down the application any further I want to have Postfix sanity check all mail that tries to leave my network destined for the rest of the world.

I only want mail that originates from within to be allowed out if it has a from address of 'example.com'.  If mail that originates from within has a from address of 'someotherdomain.com' that mail should be blocked via Postfix.

To clarify, how do I configure Postfix to only allow mail, which originated within my local network, to be allowed out IF that mail has a FROM address of one of my domain names?

The only way I've figured out how to do this so far is as follows.  But is there anything simpler?

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:

smtpd_restriction_classes =
        external_sender_access
        internal_sender_access

# Intended for mail originating from outside our networks
external_sender_access =
        # Verify MAIL_FROM on incoming mail
        check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/external_sender_access
        # Allow all other incoming mail
        permit

# Intended for mail originating from within our networks
internal_sender_access =
        # Verify MAIL_FROM on outgoing mail
        check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/internal_sender_access
        # Block all other outbound mail
        reject

# Restrictions applied in the context of the MAIL FROM command.
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        reject_non_fqdn_sender
        reject_unknown_sender_domain
        # Access rules for specific 'sender' data based upon client IP
        check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/network_sender_access
        permit
```

```
/etc/postfix/network_sender_access:

# Localhost
127.0.0.0/24        internal_sender_access

# Inside Networks
192.168.0.0/16      internal_sender_access

# Everything else
0.0.0.0/0           external_sender_access
```

```
/etc/postfix/internal_sender_access:

example.com OK
.example.com OK
```

```
/etc/postfix/external_sender_access:

example.com REJECT You're not from here!
.example.com REJECT You're not from here!
```

postconf -n output for this configuration:

```
alias_database = dbm:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
biff = no
body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
disable_vrfy_command = yes
external_sender_access = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/external_sender_access permit
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_protocols = ipv4,ipv6
internal_sender_access = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/internal_sender_access reject
local_header_rewrite_clients = permit_inet_interfaces,permit_mynetworks
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -t
mailbox_size_limit = 0
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
minimal_backoff_time = 1800s
mydestination = $myorigin, $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = /etc/postfix/local_networks
queue_directory = /data/postfix
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_generic_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/generic
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_access permit
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining reject_multi_recipient_bounce permit
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname permit_mynetworks check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_access permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_override reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_unknown_recipient_domain regexp:/etc/postfix/regexp_access permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination reject_unlisted_recipient check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023 permit
smtpd_restriction_classes = external_sender_access internal_sender_access
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender reject_unknown_sender_domain check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/network_sender_access permit
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
virtual_alias_domains = example.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual.d/example.com
```

**EDIT: Below is  alternative configuration I tried using 'reject_unlisted_sender'.**

When I try using this configuration, mail sent 'From: does_not_exist@example.com' bounces (as expected), but mail sent 'From: blah@not_my_domain.com' is allowed out without problem, which is exactly what I do not want.

```
# Restrictions applied in the context of the MAIL FROM command.
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        reject_non_fqdn_sender
        reject_unknown_sender_domain
        check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/outgoing_senders
        # Access rules for specific 'sender' data
        check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
        permit
```

```
/etc/postfix/outgoing_senders:
192.168.0.0/16  reject_unlisted_sender, permit
```

```
/etc/postfix/sender_access:

example.com REJECT You're not from here!
.example.com REJECT You're not from here!
```

postconf -n output for this configuration:

```
alias_database = dbm:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
biff = no
body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
disable_vrfy_command = yes
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_protocols = ipv4,ipv6
local_header_rewrite_clients = permit_inet_interfaces,permit_mynetworks
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -t
mailbox_size_limit = 0
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
minimal_backoff_time = 1800s
mydestination = $myorigin, $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = /etc/postfix/local_networks
queue_directory = /data/postfix
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_generic_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/generic
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_access permit
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining reject_multi_recipient_bounce permit
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname permit_mynetworks check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_access permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_override reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_unknown_recipient_domain regexp:/etc/postfix/regexp_access permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination reject_unlisted_recipient check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023 permit
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender reject_unknown_sender_domain check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/outgoing_senders check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access permit
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
virtual_alias_domains = example.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual.d/example.com
```

Comment: I've tried using 'reject_unlisted_sender' but that only seemed to do anything when the FROM domain was listed in my virtual_aliases tables.  Any other domain was ignored and the mail was allowed out.

Comment: (1) Please provide the output of `postconf -n`. (2) Where you put `reject_unlisted_sender` in your restriction?

Comment: To forcing both `external_sender_access` and `internal_sender_access`, yes you need smtpd_restriction_classes. For other method, see the [FAQ here](http://serverfault.com/a/664483/218590)

Comment: Alternate configuration using `reject_unlisted_sender` and `postconf -n` output added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that what you see in your postfix was intended behavior of `reject_unlisted_sender`. [This documentation page](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient) clearly states 4 conditions when postfix rejected your email

> - The sender domain matches **$mydestination**, **$inet_interfaces** or **$proxy_interfaces**, but the sender is not listed in **$local_recipient_maps**, and **$local_recipient_maps** is not null.
> - The sender domain matches **$virtual_alias_domains** but the sender is not listed in **$virtual_alias_maps**.
> - The sender domain matches **$virtual_mailbox_domains** but the sender is not listed in **$virtual_mailbox_maps**, and **$virtual_mailbox_maps** is not null.
> - The sender domain matches **$relay_domains** but the sender is not listed in **$relay_recipient_maps**, and **$relay_recipient_maps** is not null.

When the sender address doesn't match any condition above, *by default* postfix will *permit* it.

---

Back to your original question: *The only way I've figured out how to do this so far is as follows. **But is there anything simpler**?*

**NO**, your only options is likely SMTPD restiction classes. For other solution, you can use any [policy server addon](http://www.postfix.org/addon.html#policy) such as postfwd, policyd and others.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the feedback.  It's nice to know I didn't miss something completely obvious.

Answer (score 5):

**YES** I think.

Create a new Postscript regular expression access file `/etc/postfix/allowed_senders`, for example:

```
/@microsoft.com$/ OK
/@bbc.co.uk$/ OK
/@abc.net.au$/ OK
// REJECT
```

Test it with e.g.

```
postmap -q bill@microsoft.com regexp:/etc/postfix/allowed_senders
```

Use it by adding the line

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/allowed_senders
```

to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

That should do it. This is working for me, and on an old Postfix version from before the date of this question, so I don't think I'm relying on anything added since.

Comment: You need to add postmap /etc/postfix/allowed_senders to make the .db file of course, but then it seems to work as of Postfix 3.1.0 Ubuntu 16.04LTS. Perfect, thanks.

Comment: It's a `regexp:` lookup not a `hash:` lookup, so you don't need to use `postmap` to create a `.db` version in order for it to work. http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types

Comment: Here `check_sender_access` is the name of a supposedly preexisting file, right? Or is it some sort of a directive?

Comment: I see that `check_sender_access` is a special directive, as explained in the reference at: https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html

Comment: But I think that this solution is similar to external_sender_access and internal_sender_access classes without permit and reject at the end. And also lacks the IP matching that triggers the external_ or internal_ behavior.